# Cannot Migrate with taps ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to migrate my rails database from sqlite3 to postgresql so I can push to heroku. I'm trying to migrate the data as well.
Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'taps', '>= 0.3.22'
gem "tilt", '~> 1.4.1'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'


# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

end

group :production do

  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma'

end
```

I also changed my database.yml file to migrate to postgres

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gainxp_development
  pool: 5
  username: sam
  password: pass
  host: localhost


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gainxp_test
  pool: 5
  username: sam
  password: pass
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gainxp_production
  pool: 5 
  username: sam
  password: pass
  host: localhost
```

I ran the following command to start my taps server and it started correctly:

```
taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 sam pass -p $PORT
```

In a different terminal I ran:

```
sudo taps pull postgres://sam:pass@localhost/gainxp_development http://sam:pass@localhost:$PORT
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Receiving schema
Unable to fetch tables information from http://sam:pass@0.0.0.0:8080. Please check the server log.
```

My pg_hba.conf file is the following

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

When I visit the sinatra server taps is running on, I get the following appear on a white  background:

```
Taps >= v0.3.22 is required for this server
```

I've been at this for weeks trying to migrate my db. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I fixed the issue by running `sequel -C sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://sam:pass@localhost/gainxp_development` and everything worked. *Self Five*